# Python - Reading a CSV as a command line argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, csv

As the title says, I'm working on a project where the input files will be command line arguments and im a little confused how to read them. I know code it in python where it looks like

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
     lines = file.read().splitlines()
```

But I would assume it would be different for command line argument objects. I have also attached a picture of what the whole command line argument would look like.[image]

Where - is an input and -- is an output.

Comment: The code you showed does not care whether `filepath` is a hardcoded string or a command-line argument. What are you *actually* struggling with?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
Off-site links and [images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: @DeepSpace What do I put so ensure that it reads that though. Would I just put filepath = 'TeamMap.csv'? And since im reading three files I just have 3 open/read methods with the given csv names hard coded into the filepath right

Comment: for simple arguments you could use `sys.argv` to get values from command line - ie. `open(sys.argv[1])` - but  for something more complex you should see module [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Answer (score 0):

For something simple you could use `sys.argv` to get command arguments.

If you run

```
python report.py TeamMap.csv
```

then you can get `TeamMap.csv` with `sys.argv[1]`

```
import sys

#filepath = sys.argv[1]

with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:
    lines = file.read().splitlines()
```

It may need also `len(sys.argv) > 1` to check if there was argument in command line

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    #filepath = sys.argv[1]
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:
        lines = file.read().splitlines()
else:
    print('You need file path')
    exit(1)
```

But for something more complex you should see module [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-t', help='path to team csv')
parser.add_argument('-p', help='path to product csv')
parser.add_argument('-s', help='path to sales csv')
parser.add_argument('--team-report', help='path to team report')
parser.add_argument('--product-report', help='path to product report')
args = parser.parse_args() 

with open(args.t) as file:
    lines = file.read().splitlines()
```